# Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal

Tags: haskell, char

guys, i just started learning haskell (and to code) and i have ran into a problem that i can't figure out. So there is this exercise in which i have to present the number of solutions for a 2nd degree equation.

```
valid a b c = if [a,b,c] == [0,0,0] then False
     else (if [a,b] == [0,0] then False
     else (if a == 0 then False 
     else True)) --function to make sure it is a 2nd degree eq

nRaizes a b c = if valid a b c == False then "not a valid eq" 
     else (if (b^2 - 4 * a * c) > 0 then 2
     else (if ((b^2 - 4 * a * c) == 0) then 1 
     else 0))
```

Everything looked fine to me, but when i try to load the script in GHCI i get the error message:

```
Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘2’
    from the context (Num a, Ord a)
      bound by the inferred type of
               nRaizes :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> [Char]
      at ficha1.hs:(18,1)-(21,13)
    In the expression: 2
    In the expression:
      (if (b * b - 4 * a * c) > 0 then
       2
       else
           (if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) == 0) then 1 else 0))
    In the expression:
      if valid a b c == False then
          "not a valid eq"
      else
          (if (b * b - 4 * a * c) > 0 then
           2
           else
               (if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) == 0) then 1 else 0))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this code? And how can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: _Always use type signatures_. What type do you want the result of `nRaizes` to be?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what signatures are, i am really just starting x). I want the result of nRaizes to be either the number 2, 1 or 0. Thanks.

Comment: A type signature specifies what sorts of objects a function takes as arguments, and which sorts of objects the result are supposed to be. For example, `length :: [a] -> Int` specifies that `length` takes a list of arbitrary-typed arguments and yields a machine-size integer as the result.

Answer (score 7):

As I already commented, you should always have a type signature, before even writing any actual code. First make it clear what the *purpose* of your code is, before actually implementing anything!

So, `valid` takes three numbers and checks them in some way, yielding `False` or `True` – i.e., a boolean. Hence, a valid signature would be

```
valid :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
```

This would limit the arguments to machine-sized integers – fast but not overflow-safe. It could also be

```
valid :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
```

or, for floating-point real numbers,

```
valid :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Bool
```

In fact, you don't need to settle on a particular type: it can be *any* number type, it just needs to support equality comparison. The “correct” signature would be

```
valid :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

That's indeed also what GHC infers if you just give it the code without a type signature:

```
Prelude> :t valid
valid :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

But the compiler can only get this right by itself because the function `valid` happens to be type-correct. If you put in some mistake, then the compiler has no idea what the type *should* be, and hence likely infer some nonsensical type that leads to a cryptic error message. (This is only one of the reasons why you should write the signature first.)

That's what happened in `nraized`. This also takes three numbers and gives one number. Let's keep it simple:

```
valid :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Int
```

That should certainly be ok (though you can certainly make it more generic).

Now the error message is much clearer:

```
<interactive>:16:87:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the expression: "not a valid eq"
    In the expression:
      if valid a b c == False then
          "not a valid eq"
      else
          (if (b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c) > 0 then
               2
           else
               (if ((b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c) == 0) then 1 else 0))
```

What this tells you is that `"not a valid eq"` is incompatible with the type `Int`. Pretty obvious actually, isn't it? A function that's supposed to return `0`, `1` or `2` shouldn't be able to return a *string*!

If you really want this to be an error case, you should mark it as such:

```
nRaizes a b c = if valid a b c == False then error "not a valid eq"
     ...
```

Here, the string is *not* a result: if that case is encountered, the program will simply be aborted and the error message prompted at the user, instead of trying to pass it on to further functions (which couldn't possibly give meaningful results anymore, just yet stranger errors).

---

### A couple of stylistic notes

- Generally avoid nesting `if` with explicit mention of `True` and `False` – this is needlessly complicated: comparisons yield booleans anyway. `valid` just gives false if *any* of the equalities hold; this could be written

  ```
  valid a b c = if [a,b,c] == [0,0,0]
                 || [a,b] == [0,0]
                 || a == 0
                then False 
                else True
  ```

  ...but that's just the same as

  ```
  valid a b c = not ([a,b,c] == [0,0,0] || [a,b] == [0,0] || a == 0)
  ```

  or indeed

  ```
  valid a b c = [a,b,c] /= [0,0,0] && [a,b] /= [0,0] && a /= 0
  ```
- Anyway, these checks are heavily redundant. If `a` is not `0` then the list equalities can't possibly hold either! So,

  ```
  valid a b c = a /= 0
  ```

  would work just as well. Actually you're not even using the `b` and `c` argument, so just write

  ```
  valid a _ _ = a /= 0
  ```

  ...or just don't define `valid` by itself at all: simply inline the condition `a /= 0`.

  ```
  nRaizes a b c = if (a /= 0) == False then error "not a valid eq" 
        ...
  ```

  which is of course again completely roundabout: simply use

  ```
  nRaizes a b c = if a == 0 then error "not a valid eq" 
        ...
  ```
- That still leaves you with some ugly nested `if`s in nasty nested parens. Haskellers don't like that, the preferred style is to use *guards*:

  ```
  nRaizes a b c
     | a == 0            = error "not a valid eq" 
     | b^2 - 4*a*c > 0   = 2
     | b^2 - 4*a*c == 0  = 1 
     | otherwise         = 0
  ```
- Still not optimal: you're computing the discriminant twice. Why not:

  ```
  nRaizes a b c
     | a == 0     = error "not a valid eq" 
     | d > 0      = 2
     | d == 0     = 1 
     | otherwise  = 0
   where d = b^2 - 4*a*c
  ```

While `error` *can* be used like that, I wonder why you check this anyway at that point. If `a==0` then it's not really a second-order polynomial, but so what? It still has a number of solutions. Really the error case should probably if *all* the coefficients are zero (because the number of solutions would be infinite). Hence I think the code you really want is probably the following:

```
nRaizes :: (Eq a, Floating a) => a -> a -> a -> Int
nRaizes a b c
  | all (==0) [a,b,c]  = error "Equation has infinite solutions" 
  | d > 0              = 2
  | d == 0             = 1 
  | otherwise          = 0
 where d = b^2 - 4*a*c
```

Comment: Wow.. thanks a lot!! I had no idea of how bad this was, and your answer is definitely going to help me a lot! Thanks man.

Comment: @JoséPedroPinto, the best way to learn is to make lots of mistakes and learn how to fix them! So keep learning. You got really lucky with this answer, but then again people who put in the effort make their own luck :-)